# JPanel vs JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am learning Java gui. The way I learnt to create a window is to inherit or Extend `JFrame` class and it is good to use it, as `JFrame` contains all the properties of a Window. Now If I want to add something to this window, I need to use `add()` method. But Today I came across `JPanel` which also creates a windows and we can add stuff by `jpanelObjec.add()`.

What is the difference between the two methods? Are they somehow related?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497889/difference-between-jpanel-jframe-jcomponent-and-japplet

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You should not extend the `JFrame` class unnecessarily (only if you are adding extra functionality to the `JFrame` class)

**JFrame**:

`JFrame` extends `Component` and `Container`.

It is a top level container used to represent the minimum requirements for a window. This includes `Border`s, resizability (is the `JFrame` resizeable?), title bar, controls (minimize/maximize allowed?), and event handlers for various `Event`s like `windowClose`, `windowOpened` etc.

**JPanel**:

`JPanel` extends `Component`, `Container` and `JComponent`

It is a generic class used to group other `Component`s together.

- It is useful when working with `LayoutManager`s e.g. `GridLayout` f.i adding components to different `JPanel`s which will then be added to the `JFrame` to create the gui. It will be more manageable in terms of `Layout` and re-usability.
- It is also useful for when painting/drawing in Swing, you would override `paintComponent(..)` and of course have the full joys of double buffering.

A Swing GUI cannot exist without a top level container like (`JWindow`, `Window`, `JFrame` `Frame` or `Applet`), while it may exist without `JPanel`s.

Comment: actually, [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) does not extend `JComponent` and `JContainer`.

Answer (score 53):

`JFrame` is the window; it can have one or more `JPanel` instances inside it.  `JPanel` is *not* the window.

You need a Swing tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/