# Can i ask what is the difference between Jframe and JPanel and which is primary in coding

Tags: java, jframe

I wanna know what is the difference between `JFrame` and `Jpanel` in simpler way I used to work with `Application Form` in VS and it's not the same for what I see 
I have hard time to figure if I should use Jframe or jpanel and which has the priority in codes

**I'm trying my best with java**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212431/jpanel-vs-jframe-in-java

Answer (score 1):

JFrame is the actual frame, the window that pops up.
JPanel is the layout inside the frame, so you can add multiple JComponents to a JPanel and organize them instead of only one component in JFrame.
You can add multiple JPanels in a JFrame.

Comment: you should mention in your post that one can add multiple JPanels in a JFrame.